# Android Cordova : Cannot set property 'text' of null

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

When I try to use `cordova prepare` on my project, I got this following error :

`(node:11384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of null at updateProjectAccordingTo (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\SELL-SIGN-Android-master\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:174:51)`

[image: Screen of the error log]

I have no clue how to solve it, and where this problem come from...
If you have any idea, let me know. Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it by adding to `\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml` this line : `<string name="app_name">MyAppName</string>` !